# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, wcf-rest

I'm new for using angularJs. I'm following this article [asp.net-angularjs](https://chsakell.com/2015/08/23/building-single-page-applications-using-web-api-and-angularjs-free-e-book/) then I have problem like this:

*entryCtrl.js*

```
(function (app) {
  'use strict';
  app.controller('entryCtrl', entryCtrl);
  entryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function entryCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-entry';
  }
})(angular.module('model'));
```

*app.js*

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('model', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

  config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
  function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "scripts/spa/home/index.html",
            controller: "indexCtrl"
        })
        .when("/entry", {
            templateUrl: "scripts/spa/entry/entry.html",
            controller: "entryCtrl"
        });
  }
```

Then have error like `[ng:areq] Argument 'entryCtrl' is not a function, got undefined angular.js:11707`

But in indexCtrl.js not error. indexCtrl hv the same this like that. What I miss?

Comment: what is the angular version

Comment: like I use in that article. I use all bundles vendor

Comment: probably you have not put them in the order

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't know what do you mean. sorry

Comment: please give me little sample :(

Comment: mark as answer if it has helped

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the module as

```
var app = angular.module('model', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
app.config(config)
app.run(run);
```

also make sure you have put the scripts in the order.